# Fortify SCA exclude multiple directories/files with maven plugin

Tags: fortify

Sorry for the seemingly duplicate question but the other Fortify solutions didn't seem to fit my case. I'm doing scans/uploads via the maven sca plugin

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>com.fortify.ps.maven.plugin</groupId>
   <artifactId>sca-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>4.20</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
       <configuration>
          <projectName>sample</projectName>
          <projectVersion>${appVersion}</projectVersion>
          <exclude>**/*.(LOCAL|INT).*</exclude>
       </configuration>
</plugin>
```

and it works

This excludes all LOCAL and INT (integration testing) property files from being scanned. Additionally, I'd like to exclude archived xsds from being scanned as well:

```
<exclude>**/(*.(LOCAL|INT).*)|(xsd/archive/*)</exclude>
```

but this does not work. In fact, not even the original working pattern is found. Any ideas?

Comment: This is more a regex issue than a Maven issue, maybe you will have better luck asking a specific question about this regex.

Comment: I suppose tagging it maven won't help--I'll remove the maven tag. The problem is with how fortify evaluates the -exclude flag value. Regular unix regex doesn't seem to work right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will share my solution, albeit a little bit of work that requires you to have access to the HP fortify installation:

I was tired of fussing for a whole day with this so I did the only sensible thing and re-wrote a portion of the fortify maven plugin! I liked the separator as `;` so I changed the `TranslateMojo.java` file under the `mavin-plugin` folder as follows then re-deployed the fortify plugin:

OLD Line:

```
addOptionValuePair("-exclude", exclude);
```

NEW Line:

```
if(exclude != null && exclude.length() > 0){
   String[] excludeList = exclude.split(";");
   for(int i = 0; i < excludeList.length; i++){
      addOptionValuePair("-exclude", excludeList[i].trim());
   }
}
```

Now my project's `.pom` has this `sca-maven-plugin` definition:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.fortify.ps.maven.plugin</groupId>
  <artifactId>sca-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>4.20</version>
     <configuration>
      <projectName>sample</projectName>
      <projectVersion>${appVersion}</projectVersion>
      <exclude>**/*.(LOCAL|INT).*;**/xsd/archive/*</exclude>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The sca-translate-war.txt file that Maven generates and uses as part of the translate step now has an -exclude for each pattern provided:

`"-exclude" "**/*.(LOCAL|INT).*" "-exclude" "**/xsd/archive/*"`

This worked for me and will hopefully save someone a few hours of struggle.

Answer (score 1):

Actually instead of tweaking source code, you can hack it that way:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.fortify.ps.maven.plugin</groupId>
  <artifactId>sca-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>4.20</version>
     <configuration>
      <projectName>sample</projectName>
      <projectVersion>${appVersion}</projectVersion>
      <exclude>**/*.(LOCAL|INT).*" -exclude "**/xsd/archive/*</exclude>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Please mind the **" -exclude "** inside exclude tag! ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the `Appendix F: Maven Integration` section of the SCA User Guide, under `Excluding Files from the Scan` heading, it shows you how to exclude files.  It tells you to use a separate file for properties and to set `com.fortify.sca.exclude`.  I would instead try to just use a semicolon to separate your two exclude patterns.

Comment: Yeah, I saw the semicolon and tried that but it didn't seem to work. Using the `<exclude>` in the maven plugin is supposed to set the `com.fortify.sca.exclude`: `[warning]: No files were excluded as the file patterns: [**/*.(LOCAL|INT).*;**/xsd/archive/*] specified for -exclude option did not match any files.`

Comment: I would also like to point out that the guide is wrong about com.fortify.sca.exclude. When you provide it on the command line, it needs to be `-Dfortify.sca.exclude`. The semicolon still didn't work until the change explained in my provided solution

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having trouble getting multiple exclusions to work and thinking about patching the plugin, first check that you are using the correct separator.  It must be semicolon on Windows or colon on Linux.

Comment: in Fortify 16.10+, they changed the way you provide excluded files in the pom. Now it is <excludes> tags with nested <exclude> tags inside. Much much better--no seperators